# No window border/decoration when unity activated in virtualbox/ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, virtualbox, 18.04, window-decoration

I installed unity on my brand new ubuntu 18.04 hoping it would solve my problem with virtualbox not wanting to use the 3D acceleration. It did, 3D acceleration now works, but I don't have window decoration/border anymore. Also some menus do not show when clicked on (like the power menu, or most choice lists).

I tried `unity --replace`, it disables 3D acceleration and brings the borders back.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

So, here is a solution that worked for me. ubuntu 18.04 on virtualbox with 3D acceleration (on windows 10 host).
Step to reproduce :

1. install virtualbox 5.2.8
2. install ubuntu 18.04 from official CD image (I choose the minimal install at startup)
3. install build-essential and ubuntu-unity-desktop
4. reboot
5. install virtualbox guest extension from the virtualbox menu (not the apt-get version, maybe it works, did not test it).
6. reboot
7. ????
8. Profit !

I don't know if it worked this time because I installed unity before the guest extension or because I use the guest extension provided by virtualbox and not from the repo.

It would seem it works with unity because unity does not use X11 and virtualbox does not support X11 very well ? (not sure about that part though, lots of other thread read, I might be a bit confused)